# ReactJS - Handling large amounts of props in component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I am looking for a better way to handle a multitude of props being passed to the component `Tabs`. Currently, I am handling a child component `Tabs` from content/functions in the Parent Component. This props list will get even longer as I continue to add more. Basically, I am filling out input from my tabs and onChange am updating the copy in the parent component.

```
  <Tabs
    nav1Title='Title 1'
    nav1Content='{Nav1tab}'
    onChangeNav1={this.handleChange}
    nav2Title='Title 2'
    nav2Content='{Nav2tab}'
    onChangeNav2={this.handleChange}
    nav3Title='Title 3'
    nav3Content='{Nav3tab}'
    onChangeNav2={this.handleChange}
    onChangeText1={this.handleChange}
    onChangeText2={this.handleChange}
    onChangeText3={this.handleChange}
    onChangeText4={this.handleChange}
    onChangeText5={this.handleChange}
    onChangeText6={this.handleChange}
    onChangeText7={this.handleChange}
  />
```

Change function:

```
  handleChange(e) {
    this.setState({[e.target.name]: e.target.value})
  }
```

example of an input in `Nav1tab` child component:

```
<FunTab handleChangeText1={this.props.onChangeText1} />
```

then an input within `FunTab` child component:

Comment: Why not a unique `onChange={this.handleChange}` as it does the same for all props ?

Comment: as striped said you should refactor the `handleChange` input to take a `name` or `id` so you only need to pass it once.  Another technique could be to have a function that wraps all the props and when you call it, it would return all the props. `inputProps = () => { return { prop1, prop2... }`

Comment: What is being the question here?

Answer (score 1):

The easier way would be to just have an array of tabs and map them to TabItems like:

```
const tabOptions = [
  {
    title: "Tab title",
    content: "Tab content",
    onChange: this.handleChange
  },
  ...
]

const Tabs = (tabOptions) => (
  tabOptions.map(tab => (
    <TabItem 
         title={tab.title} 
         content={tab.content} 
         onChange={tab.onChange} 
         key={tab.title} 
    />
  ))
)
```

For something a bit more complex but more flexible look up the "Compound components" pattern (Ryan Florence gives a great explanation on a youtube talk).